# Value changes after using a permutation in a wedge-product

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, multilinear-algebra

We defined the wedge-product as follows: $ w \wedge \mu = \frac{(k + l)!}{k!l!} Alt (w \otimes \mu)  $ ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Alternating_multilinear_forms) you'll find additional information).

In the context of a proof we came to a point where we used a permutation to change the order of the inserted values of the wedge product. This permutation was defined as $  \tau:= \begin{cases} x- m, & \mbox{for }  x>m \\ x+k, & \mbox {in all other cases} \end{cases}$

Then we had the sum (where f is a k-form and g is a m-form)

$\frac{1}{k! m!} \sum_{\sigma \in \Sigma _ {k + m}} sign(\sigma) g _\sigma (v _ {k +1},...,v _ {k +m}) f _\sigma (v _ {1},...,v _ {k })$ (1)

where the $\sigma$ in the index shows that the argument values for f and g are $v_{\sigma(i)}$.

If we now use $\tau$ the following sum shall result:

$\frac{1}{k! m!} \sum_{\sigma \in \Sigma _ {k + m}} sign(\sigma ) g _{\sigma \circ \tau} (v _ {1},...,v _ {m}) f _{\sigma \circ \tau}  (v _ {m+1},...,v _ {m+k })$ (2)

May someone explain me, why (1) equals (2) and the value isn't changed by the use of $\tau$?

I attached in the edit the whole claculation:

[image]